# Can tools.jar from OpenJDK can be installed in public repository

Tags: java, licensing, gpl

Is it legal to install tools.jar from OpenJDK in public maven repository? I found at least three topics on the Internet which conclusion was that such action is forbidden for jar provided by Oracle, but can't find anything about OpenJDK. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want an opinion that you can rely on, ask a lawyer.
2. OpenJDK is licensed under the GPL (v2) with some exceptions.  The GPL explicitly allows distribution of the software, including works (such as binaries) derived from the software.  The exceptions don't change this.
3. Historically, this was not true.  But it is now.
4. See point 1.